# Godot - can I pixelate a node (Sprite)?

Tags: sprite, godot, pixelate

Can I pixelate a 2D node (`Sprite` in my case) in Godot? I need something like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

It doesn't matter how to do it: with a shader or with code or with some tweaks. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out by myself, it was pretty easy indeed. I just need a shader:

```
shader_type canvas_item;

uniform float size_x = 32.0; // blocks by x direction
uniform float size_y = 32.0; // blocks by y direction

void fragment() {
    COLOR = texture(TEXTURE, vec2(floor(UV.x * size_x) / (size_x - 1.0), floor(UV.y * size_y) / (size_y - 1.0)));
}
```

The inside of `fragment` function is scaling the `UV` up, rounds it down using `floor` and scales the result back down. The image above (in the question) is pixelated down to 32x32 size, and after using this shader the `Sprite` looks just like in the image example.

**P.S.** It doesn't work for GUI nodes, maybe I'll solve this problem.